# dismissModalViewControllerAnimated needs to finish animating first before removing from superview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've implemented the MFMailComposeViewController and encountered a problem.

In my superview, I implemented a button, when pressed, brings up in-app emailing.
Everything works fine, until when the user sends or closes the mail form.

It seems like I need to wait for the animation (dismiss the email form) to end first, before `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` can be run. If this line is run before the animation ends nothing happens and the view is not removed, thus I can't tap anything on the screen as the current UIView is not removed.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Removes the view so that delegate is passed back to the superview
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

}
```

My superview action which calls the class:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressedSendMail {
    MailComposerViewController *mailComposer = [[MailComposerViewController alloc] init];
    [self addSubview:mailComposer.view];
    [mailComposer sendMail:nil];
}
```

`[[self view] setHidden:YES];` to hide the UIView works, but I don't think this is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Present your view controller with presentModalViewController:animated:

```
MailComposerViewController *mailComposer = [[MailComposerViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

Then dismiss the modal view like you do

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

No need to add or remove the view controller's view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dispatch_after block. You can adjust the delayInSeconds to after the mail composer dismissed.

```
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    });
```

or you can try this:

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}];

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did to find out the error. But not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: I updated the code with alternate way to dismiss the view controller.

Comment: You are not showing the modal view controller correctly. Unless you have some very specific need I would follow the code in Xavi's answer.